# Can I perform SQL JOIN like operations with DAO Excel VBA Recordsets?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, join, recordset

I have two recordsets, the first (`rs1`) is a query result from Access database, the other (`rs2`) was created by converting an array built inside VBA. The first contains a series of data, the second, some descriptions related to one of the columns of the first.

I'd like to join these two recordsets into a third, having the records from the first one, and the description fields of the second. Something similar to an `INNER JOIN` in a SQL query.

Is it possible in VBA? Something like a query using `rs1` and `rs2` as tables and the necessary query structure (`SELECT xyx FROM rs1, rs2 WHERE abc`)...

Comment: I am very interested to see how you created a recordset *by converting an array built inside VBA*. What is source of this data? Feel free to show code on this programming Q/A site.

Comment: As far as I know you can't use a recordset as a query source.  you might consider taking your second recordset and inserting it into your Access DB, so you can perform the join there.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Back to drawing board :D.

Answer (score 0):

For the array in recordset conversation, I've found out this code and it works pretty well:

```
Private Function ADOCopyArrayIntoRecordset(argArray As Variant) As ADODB.Recordset 

Dim rsADO As ADODB.Recordset
Dim lngR As Long
Dim lngC As Long

Set rsADO = New ADODB.Recordset

For lngC = 1 To UBound(argArray, 2)
rsADO.Fields.Append "Fld" & lngC, adVariant
Next lngC

rsADO.Open

For lngR = 1 To UBound(argArray, 1)
For lngC = 1 To UBound(argArray, 2)
rsADO.AddNew
rsADO.Fields(lngC - 1).Value = argArray(lngR, lngC)
Next lngC
rsADO.MoveNext
Next lngR

rsADO.MoveFirst

Set ADOCopyArrayIntoRecordset = rsADO
End Function
```